# No such algorithm: PKCS11 for provider SunPKCS11-CartaoCidadao

Tags: java, keystore, pkcs#11, java-security, sunpkcs11

There are my current providers:

> 0 - Provider name: SUN
>   1 - Provider namer: SunRsaSign
>   2 - Provider name: SunEC
>
> ...
>
> 9 - Provider name: SunPKCS11-CartaoCidadao

The ninth provider is the one that I'm trying to use, which uses the pkcs11 library.

```
Provider prov = Security.getProvider("SunPKCS11-CartaoCidadao");
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", prov );
```

Using the info method I can see it's using the library:

```
System.out.println(prov.getInfo());
```

> SunPKCS11-CartaoCidadao using library /usr/local/lib/libpteidpkcs11.so

Yet, while I'm trying to get a key instance, it tells me  there's no PKCS11 for that provider, which it should.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11","SunPKCS11-CartaoCidadao");
keyStore.load( null, null );
```

> java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found
>
> Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: PKCS11 for provider SunPKCS11-CartaoCidadao

Anyone have any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Despite being able to see that the Provider was successfully added/inserted, and its `getInfo()` showing the path of the actual PKCS#11 lib of your device, the

> java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found

is given if the `slotListIndex` or `slot` (see the [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/security/pkcs11-reference-guide1.htm)) was not specified correctly. The SunPKCS11 provider lists all slots, even those that have no token present, so the `slotListIndex` should be specified accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter should be of type `Provider`.

Use the following:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11",prov);
```